# Xcode 6.4 When I Try To Add New Folder It Appears In Blue Color. I want Default Yellow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6.4

I am Using Xcode 6.4 When I try to add a new folder in my Project

**Right Click ViewControllers -> Add Files to-> New Folder**

[image]

it appears in blue color, instead of the default yellow color. How can I Get Folder In Default Color also Explain me difference between Yellow Folder And Blue Folder.

Comment: Thanks paul R And Anbu.Karthik For help me.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Right Click ViewControllers -> Add Files to-> New Folder  before adding make sure that Destination and and create group is selected.may be you are only giving reference to **Xcode**.

Hope this will help you.

[image]

Comment: most welcome @HiteshBoricha .